# Is there the symbol $n!!!$ in mathematics?

Tags: calculus

I know there are two symbol of factorial $n!$ and double factorial $n!!$ but I don't know if the $n!!!$ or more is used in mathematics.
If there is any references about this, please tell me. 
thanks for any helps

Comment: Check out the multifactorial notion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials

Comment: +1. Today I learned about double factorials, and they have an unexpected definition, so thanks for the question

Comment: I can’t resist: yes!!!

Comment: I would use something like $n!_3$ for $n!!!$ and $n!_k$ for higher ones. You can use any symbol unless it needs to be written for an exam, for a thesis you can invent symbols maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a multifactorial: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html